# OPenMP: When can a Loop be parallelized

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

For each of the following code segments, use OpenMP pragmas to make the loop parallel, or
explain why the code segment is not suitable for parallel execution.

```
a. for (i = 0; i < sqrt(x); i++)
 a[i] = 2.3 * i;
 if (i < 10)
 b[i] = a[i];
}

b. flag = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n && !flag; i++)
 a[i] = 2.3 * i;
 if (a[i] < b[i])
 flag = 1;
}

c. for (i = 0; i < n && !flag; i++)
 a[i] = foo(i);
d. for (i = 0; i < n && !flag; i++) {
 a[i] = foo(i);
 if (a[i] < b[i])
 a[i] = b[i];
}

e. for (i = 0; i < n && !flag; i++) {
 a[i] = foo(i);
 if (a[i] < b[i])
 break;
}

f. dotp = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 dotp += a[i] * b[i];
g. for (i = k; i < 2 * k; i++)
 a[i] = a[i] + a[i – k];
h. for (i = k; i < n; i++) {
 a[i] = c * a[i – k];
```

Any help regarding the above question would be very much welcome..any line of thinking..

Comment: this is not HW solving services...

Comment: @gsamaras if you could solve any one I would try all

Comment: OK then, I will give a hint @DineshReddy, but I am not solving any of the HW. Moreover, I am upvoting you, since your comment was nice, but *next time show some effort* **please**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not do your HW, but I will give a hint. When playing around with OpenMp for loops, you should be alert about the scope of the variables. For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int x=0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y < height; y++)
    {
        finalImage[x][y] = RenderPixel(x,y, &sceneData);
    }
}
```

is OK, since `x` and `y` are private variables.

What about

```
int x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(x=0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(y=0; y < height; y++)
    {
        finalImage[x][y] = RenderPixel(x,y, &sceneData);
    }
}
```

?

Here, we have defined `x` and `y` outside of the for loop. Now consider `y`. Every thread will access/write it without any synchronization, thus data races will occur, which are very likely to result in logical errors.

Read more [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/) and good luck with your HW.